# How can I compare two awk result value in bash

Tags: bash, awk

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1

declare -a myarr
myarr=($(awk '{print $2}' sim.count))
for((i=0 ;i<${#myarr[@]};i++))
do
#echo ${myarr[$i]}
#rm  "${myarr[$i]}"
awk '{if ($1 == "{$myarr[$i]}"){print $2}}' $filename > "${myarr[$i]}"
done
```

I store awk result into array and run loop to find if $filename 's column one has the same element then print column two

I have tried `if ($1 == "a|||a"){print $2}`
and it work well, but `if ($1 == "{$myarr[$i]}")` not the result I want, anything wrong ??

Comment: Why not do the comparison in awk itself?

Comment: Use `awk -v var="$val"` to pass variables from shell into awk -- you're risking injection attacks if you do direct substitution into code, as demo'd here.

Comment: And there's no point in indexing over values if you don't need the indexes themselves; just `for value in "${myarr[@]}"; do ... : something with "$value"; done`

Comment: And in general, `myarr=( $(...) )` is bad news -- it does glob expansion, not just string-splitting. Use `read -r -a myarr < <(...)` instead, and you get precise control over which characters are split on, and no unintended effects such as globbing.

Comment: What is the objective here? This looks like an [\[ XY Problem \]](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: This looks like `join` might be a simpler solution but since you don't really explain your requirements, it's hard to provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is literally comparing against `{$myarr[i]}`, not against the value associated with an entry in the shell variable by that name:

```
# original code: DOES NOT WORK (even if fixed to ${myarr[$i]})
awk '{if ($1 == "{$myarr[$i]}"){print $2}}'
```

This is because the double-quotes are still inside single-quotes, so the string is passed to awk without the shell expanding it -- and awk has no way of looking at shell variables (except ones in the environment, which requires explicit syntax to look up and doesn't apply to arrays anyhow).

---

Instead, pass your expanded value into `awk` separately:

```
awk -v tgt="${myarr[i]}" '{if ($1 == tgt) {print $2}}'
```